# Jenkins Pipeline - Active Choice Reactive Parameter

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

The following script reads all file names from a directory and displays them to the user as parameters (without extension)

```
import groovy.io.FileType

def list = []
def dir = new File("/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/grookins/folderx")

dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
list.add(file.getName().split("\\.",  2)[0])
}
return list
```

It works fine if I paste the code into the Groovy Script area in the UI right here
[image]

[image]

Now if I paste the script into a Jenkinsfile,
[image]

for some reason, the backslashes are turning into a simple backslash in the UI after running the script from scm
[image]

and the parameters are gone
[image]

Can someone help me to find the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

By try and error i found out that the regex in the split function is interpreted differently in the UI than in the Jenkinsfile. In the Jenkinsfile 4 backslashes are required to escape the dot in the UI.

This is how the entry in the Jenkinsfile looks like:

```
list.add(file.getName().split("\\\\.",  2)[0])
```

Comment: To me it looks like the dot must be escaped twice. First in the Jenkinsfile to show up as a valid regex in the UI and then in the UI to not be interpreted as a special character.
Does anyone know the reason for this behavior?

Comment: the dot can also be escaped by using square brackets.
`list.add(file.getName().split("[.]",  2)[0])`